# Sorting and paging compiled queries

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is it possible to compile queries which will be used with paging and sorting? For example does this make sense:

```
this.query = CompiledQuery.Compile<...>(
..
from row in dbx.Table select row
)

..

var select = this.query.OrderBy(..).Skip(..).Take(..);
```

Is this plausible? Or will it recompile every time Order, Skip, Take parameters change? Should I go back to regular queries instead of compiling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the query would be recompiled every time.

However, if you put your paging *inside* the compiled query, then it will compile the paging part, as well.

Comment: You mean like this: this.query = CompiledQuery.Compile<...>(
..
(from row in dbx.Table select row).OrderBy(param1).Skip(param2).Take(param3)
)

Comment: Note that not all DBs can use params for `OrderBy`, though